# Spring bean constructor-arg rejects the object i want to pass in (implements myInterface), constructor param is of type myInterface

Tags: java, spring, interface, spring-security, spring-bean

I'm attempting to generate a bean of type AuthenticationController.  The constructor for Authentication controller has one parameter of type DataSource, called securityDataSource.  In my security context xml I declare the bean using the following code.

Excerpt from webSecurityConfig.xml:

```
<bean id="authoritiesConroller" 
       class="honors.uh.edu.security.AuthoritiesController">
        <constructor-arg ref="securityDataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Here is the definition of the bean securityDataSource:

```
<bean name="securityDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
```

AuthoritiesController.java

```
package honors.uh.edu.security;

import honors.uh.edu.pojo.User;

import java.sql.Types;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport;
import org.springframework.jdbc.object.SqlUpdate;
public class AuthoritiesController  extends JdbcDaoSupport {


    private InsertAuthority insertAuthority;

    public AuthoritiesController(DataSource securityDataSource) {
        super();
        insertAuthority = new InsertAuthority(securityDataSource);


    }

    public void create(User user, String authority) {
        insertAuthority.insert(user, authority);
    }

    /********* Inner Classes  ************/
    protected class InsertAuthority extends SqlUpdate {
        protected InsertAuthority(DataSource ds) {
            super(ds, "INSERT INTO authorities VALUES (?, ?)");
            declareParameter(new SqlParameter(Types.VARCHAR));
            declareParameter(new SqlParameter(Types.VARCHAR));
            compile();
        }

        protected void insert(User user, String authority) {
            Object[] objs = new Object[] { user.getUsername(), authority };
            super.update(objs);
        }

    }
}
```

The error I get in return is `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is required`.  Why would it now allow this? DriverManagerDataSource is an implementation of DataSource so shouldn't I be allowed to pass it as a parameter?

EDIT: Here is the full error-

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authoritiesConroller' defined in class path resource [spring/webSecurityConfig.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760) ~[spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) ~[spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) ~[spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) ~[spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_05]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_05]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is required
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport.checkDaoConfig(JdbcDaoSupport.java:112) ~[spring-jdbc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DaoSupport.afterPropertiesSet(DaoSupport.java:44) ~[spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

Comment: can you verify fully qualified names once again, also which version of Spring

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by fully qualified names.  I'm using 4.0.3.RELEASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!  The `<constructor-arg...../>` bit was never the problem.  The issue was that because my class AuthenticationController was extending class JdbcDaoSupport it expected me to declare a property called "dataSource".  It was never an issue of type conflict.

The now functional bean declaration looks like:

```
<bean id="authoritiesConroller" class="honors.uh.edu.security.AuthoritiesController">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="securityDataSource"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="securityDataSource"/>
</bean>
```

I'm sure there is a better way of doing this so as not to pass in the dataSource twice, but this at least solved the problem.  Thanks for your help!